# problem in adding java date in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, date

here is the code

```
String DateOfBirth[]=strDOB.split("/");
Date dateOfBirth = new Date();
dateOfBirth.setYear(Integer.parseInt(DateOfBirth[2].trim()));
dateOfBirth.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(DateOfBirth[1].trim()));
dateOfBirth.setDate(Integer.parseInt(DateOfBirth[0].trim()));
 java.text.SimpleDateFormat DateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
strDOB = DateFormat.format(dateOfBirth);
 DBProcess.QueryExecuter("INSERT INTO patients(patient_id,first_name,last_name,middle_name,birth_dt) VALUES (\""+Double.parseDouble(strPatientID.trim())+"\",\""+strFirstname+"\",\""+strLastname+"\",\""+strMiddlename+"\",\""+strDOB +"\");");
```

Comment: and ... what exactly is the problem? A description of the error (and the expected behaviour) would be quite helpful.

Comment: Grab the value of that constant string `INSERT INTO ....` and execute it directly in MySQL client. It will fail. Then make it work in that client and apply the changes to your java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my.

See if this is better:

```
private static final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into patients(patient_id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, birth_dt) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
Date dob = inputFormatter.parse(strDOB);
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
// bind your values here.
int numRowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
```

I can't understand why you'd write that code to parse a date string when DateFormat was born to do it.  And I certainly hope that your `birth_dt` column is of type Date in your database.  Anything else is utterly foolish.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, do you use java.util.Date or java.sql.Date ?

The best way to insert a Java date in MySQL (or other DB) is to use the PreparedStatement, and the java.sql.Date class :

```
java.sql.Date theDate = new Date(longTime);
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table(id,date) VALUES (?,?)");
stmt.setInt(1, 123);
stmt.setDate(2, theDate);
stmt.execute();
```